# Intermittent WCF timeout issue

Tags: wcf, timeout, wcf-security

Client is frequently experiencing the following error

> Additional information: Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout (00:00:00).  The current negotiation leg is 1 (00:00:00).

This suggests somewhere I'm specifying a timeout period of 0 seconds which I am not. The binding in question I've explicitly set a timeout for 15 seconds

```
<ws2007HttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsUsername" sendTimeout="00:00:15" receiveTimeout="00:00:15">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message establishSecurityContext="false"
                 negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
```

As I said it is quite intermittent. Quite a lot of the time this works and once it does work it continues to do so for 15 minutes or so until the failures start again. I've turned on WCF tracing but it doesn't tell me anything more than I'm conveying here.